# How to redirect following submit button code to same page and if possible without reloading

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax, wordpress

I have created a code that run in a popup of WordPress website, the purpose of this code is to validate entered data available in mysql db table if available it displays relative code else it executes other code.

I have tried

```
 action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>"
```

and

```
headlocation(.......)
```

but none worked, it is submitting code and redirecting to `index.php` to display results.

```
<style><?php include 'search-zip.css'; ?>
</style>

<?php 

include 'search-config.php';
$conn = OpenCon();
?>
<h3 class="formhead">Available in</h3>
<h2 class="formhead">Melbourne Inner Suburbs</h2>
<form class="form-wrapper"  action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" method="post">
<input type="text" name="$POSTCODE" id="search" size="25" maxlength="35" value="<?php echo $_REQUEST['$POSTCODE'] ?>" />
<input type="submit"
name="submit" value="Search" id="submit"></form>
<p class="form-text">Please search your postal code for service availability</p>

<?

if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {

{
   $zipcode=$_REQUEST['$POSTCODE'];
   $sql = "SELECT * FROM service_location WHERE zipcode = $zipcode";
$result = $conn->query($sql);



if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    ?>
    <style>.formhead{display:none;} .form-wrapper{display:none;} .form-text{display:none;}</style>
<div class="available">
<img class="zipimage" src="https://www.hastygrocer.com.au/wp-content/uploads/2019/07/hasty-grocer-available-popup-image.png" alt="Happy Minion" >
<h2 style="text-align: center;">Experience Melbourne's</h2>
<h2 style="text-align: center;"><i style="color: #3aafa9; font-family: Faster One script=all rev=2; font-size: 60px;">Fast</i> &amp; <b style="color: green; font-family: Aladin; font-size: 60px;">Fresh </b></h2>
<h2 style="text-align: center;">Grocery Delivery</h2> 
<span class="pum-close popmake-close "><button  class="zipbutton" type="button">Shop</button></span></div>

    <?

} else {

?>
<style>.formhead{display:none;} </style>
<div class="available">
   <h3 style="text-align: center;">Get Notified When Available in <b style=" text-align: center;font-weight: 800; font-family: arial; color: #3aafa9;"><?php echo "$zipcode"?></b></h3> 
<div class="zipform"><?php echo do_shortcode( '[contact-form-7 id="613" title="PopUp"]' ); ?></div>
</div>
<?
}
}}

?>
```

I created this code to redirect to same page.

but this is redirecting to `index.php` to display result.

please help me in fixing this using any php or `ajax` that may fix this code.

sorry I am not an expert developer I got code from internet and created the following code.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Just try to use `wp_redirect( 'http://mywebsite.com/login', 301 ); 
        exit;`

Comment: Hi Kaushal,

Thanks for your response 

actually this code appears in every page of my website as a popup, so I want to execute in that page and redirect to same page where user is seeing that popup in website

Comment: https://www.hastygrocer.com.au/shop/ please visit this url it would give you some reference what the issue is.

Comment: Hi Naveen . Can you use javascript there. like `window.location.reload()`

Comment: If you want to send a form simply to the current URL, then just leave the action attribute out completely.

Answer (score 0):

See this part of code: `action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>"`

The submit will be performed to the link passed from the $_SERVER array, but PHP manual says:

> $_SERVER is an array containing information such as headers, paths, and script locations. The entries in this array are created by the web server. There is no guarantee that every web server will provide any of these.

Try to make an `<? echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>` and see what is printed. You will probably get the index.php location.

Try to set the action to the page that contains the form.